# Expiring a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, caching

I saved some data returned from ajax in javascript variable. I would like to invalidate this variable after some time period, say one hour.

I can potentially write some setTimeout functions to handle this, but I just feel this is not optimal.

Another way is to save in cookie and set expiration, but the overhead may be unnecessary.

Is there other way that can handle this situation more elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the actual variable actually exists that long (the page stays open), just do what every cache does: save a timestamp and check for it.

```
var cache = { timestamp : null, data : null };

function setData(data) {
    cache.data      = data;
    cache.timestamp = new Date;
}

function getData(maxAge) {
    if (/* compare cache.timestamp to now - maxAge */) {
        return null;
    }
    return cache.data;
}
```

Comment: But a real cache would free the memory at some time?

Comment: Well, then also unset the data when you notice it expired. Caches don't necessarily remove data right when they expire, but they may. That requires a periodic garbage collector to run.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a variable that indicates when the value expires.

```
var foo = "bar";
var foo_expires_on = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 5); // +5 hours
```

deceze's answer is a more formal (monad) implementation.